# Port mapper table not found

Tags: boot, bios, flashing

I just got a new acer revocenter, with intel atom d525 in it. When i boot it up there was no options to get to the bios setting. So I am trying to flash the bios.

I created a bootable disk with `iflash2.exe` and the bios file. Ran this command in dos on the bootable usb stick  `iflash2 /pf mw0131p.bio` . however i got the following message.

```
IFLASH2 version 2.5 - build 064

Port Mapper Table Signature not found
```

how can i resolve this and flash my bios?

Answer (score 0):

i just put the bio on a flash drive and hit F7 on boot and the BIOS started to update itself. According to the README of the bios update Intel Mainboards from 2009 onwards should support this method.